# Non-Overlapping Spheres with vector class

Tags: c++

I'm trying to study non-overlapping spheres. I have 4 vectors: xcentro, ycentro and zcentro, which contain the coordenates of the centers of these spheres, and r with contain their radius. What I want to do is compare the distance with the sum of the radii of two spheres to check if the overlap or not. Here's the code I have:

```
 i=0;
    j=0;
    for (vector<double>::iterator h = xcentro.begin(); h != xcentro.end(); h++)
    {
        for (vector<double>::iterator w = xcentro.begin(); w != xcentro.end(); w++)
        {
            d.insert(d.begin() + i, sqrt(pow(xcentro[i] - xcentro[j], 2) + pow(ycentro[i] - ycentro[j], 2) + pow(zcentro[i] - zcentro[j], 2)));
            cout << "i: " << i << endl;
            cout << "j: " << j << endl;
            cout << "Radio i : " << r[i] << "Radio j: " << r[j] << endl;

            if ((d[i] < (r[i] + r[j])) && (r[i] >= r[j]) && (i != j))
            {
                //eliminar la esfera j-esima
                r.erase(r.begin() + j);
                xcentro.erase(xcentro.begin() + j);
                ycentro.erase(ycentro.begin() + j);
                zcentro.erase(zcentro.begin() + j);
                cout << "Dora1" << endl;
            }
            if ((d[i] < (r[i] + r[j])) && (r[i] < r[j]))
            {
                //eliminar la esfera i-esima
                r.erase(r.begin() + j);
                xcentro.erase(xcentro.begin() + i);
                ycentro.erase(ycentro.begin() + i);
                zcentro.erase(zcentro.begin() + i);
                cout << "Dora2" << endl;
            }
            if (d[i] >= (r[i] + r[j]))
            {
                //eliminar la esfera j-esima
                r.erase(r.begin() + j);
                xcentro.erase(xcentro.begin() + j);
                ycentro.erase(ycentro.begin() + j);
                zcentro.erase(zcentro.begin() + j);
                cout << "Dora3" << endl;
            }

            j++;
        }
    i++;    
}
```

However, the code doesn't run till the end, it stops but no error code apperas. Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue with some hardcoded data? You should be aware that `erase` invalidates iterators, so you need to account for that. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase

Comment: Prefer a vector of x/y/z tuples over three distinct vectors. It will simplify your code a lot.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I've upload the .cpp and the input files in the following link: https://github.com/elenaferga/nonoverlappinspheres/. The code has several parts. The first one is reading the input data, ths second one is sorting the vectors so the sphere with bigger radius is the first one, and finally I'm trying to erase the overlapping spheres so I keep the biggest non-overlapping spheres, and I want to write the coordenates and radii of these spheres in an output file

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I'm completly new in C++ and I ha veno clue how using tuples over three distinct vectors, I'm trying to do the easiest for me

Comment: `struct point { float x, y, z;}`, that's what I meant. You can also use `std::tuple` or define a more complex type, but a simple struct will give you a good benefit already without being too complex for a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

After you erase an element, you can't access `[i]` anymore.

```
            zcentro.erase(zcentro.begin() + j); // <--- this make the vector shorter
            cout << "Dora1" << endl;
        }
        if ((d[i] < (r[i] + r[j])) && (r[i] < r[j])) // <--- this accesses out of bound
        {
```

You need to split your code in two parts:

1. checking whether you delete or not.
2. If you delete, after deleting, check where your iterator is and whether it still makes sense

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous issues in your code. Here are some of them:

1. You use `h` and `w` iterators for your loops, but never use those within the body of the loops.
2. You use `i` and `j` as index variables within the loops, but `j` is never reset to 0 when the inner loop restarts for the next outer loop. This will cause an out-of-bounds access of your vectors.
3. You erase the wrong element from `r` in the middle if block.
4. You attempt to access elements after they have been erased, which will either access the wrong element or be an invalid access if it is now past the end of the vector.

This would be a lot easier if you had a struct with all your x, y, z, and r values stored in one vector (an array of structures) rather than a multiple vectors (akin to a structure of arrays).

Comment: I understand issues 2 and 3 and I have actually fixed them. As for the first issue, I use h and w iterators to stop the loop when the end of the vectors is reached. For the fourth issue... I don't understand why I'm attempting to access elementos which have been erased. How is that possible?

Comment: @ElenaFernandez With the way you're using them, the loops should use `i` and `j` and not iterators. If you erase element `j`, then access `r[j]`, you're accessing what was `r[j + 1]` before the erase. If you erase the last element in the vector, `r[j]` will be out-of-bounds. There are also issues with accessing `r[i]` if `i > j` (because the element `r[i]` before the erase will be `r[i - 1]` after the erase).

Comment: I use h and w in the loops because I had some issues using i and j, so using h and w the loop will end when i have "reached" the end of each vector, I think. Because of this, I shouldn't have any problema with accessing an out-of-bound element, right? And for fixing the issue of accesing the j+1 element when accesing the element j, I had thought on adding j-- in each if block, but I'm not sure of this